# How do I make a command to store user input on a Discord Bot in C#?

Tags: c#, discord

I have a Discord Bot I made with Discord.net.

Currently I have a command that posts a string, but I wanted to make one that posted a string that was previously input by the user.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord.WebSocket;

namespace SuccubusBot.Modules
{
    public class Ping : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        [Command("hold")]
        public async Task PingAsync()
        {
            string oneL = "L";
            await ReplyAsync(oneL);



        }
    }
}
```

My only experience with receiving user input is with console projects so I am unsure of what to do here.

Comment: Do you mean like a simple command that outputs what the user inputs?

Comment: Yes. To store it as a string to re-post.

Comment: I have an answer that may hopefully fill your requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple command that outputs what the user inputs could be written like this:

```
[Command("say")]
public async Task Say([Remainder] string echo)
{
    // ReplyAsync is a method on ModuleBase
    await ReplyAsync(echo);
}
```

Example usage would be (If your commands starts with prefix "!"):

```
!say Hello
```

The bot would output on the channels that it is allowed to type:

```
Hello
```

The key in this is the [Remainder] on the argument list. It tells the developer that the user will pass a command with a string after it.

Comment: This looks like what I need. I will try it after work.

Comment: This is the solution. Thank you so much.